# Numpy dot product returns array of [inf]

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I'm new in python and learning a deep learning so I have created a basic neural network code using python. There is one neuron having input values as (1 to 49) and single output as `sin(input)`. All I have done something as:

input as :

```
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.],.....[49]]
```

output as:

```
array([[ 0.84147098],
       [ 0.90929743],
       [ 0.14112001],
       [-0.7568025 ],.....]
```

Full Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel("C:/Users/neural_network.xlsx")
total_rows=data.shape[0]
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore') 

def sigmoid(x):
    d=(np.exp(x)/(1+np.exp(x)))
    return d

def derivative_sigmoid(x):
    derivative=x/(1-x)
    return derivative


epoch=5000
hidden_layer=3
input_neurons=1
output_neurons=1
learning_rate=0.1
input_array=data['input'].values.reshape(total_rows,1)
input_array=input_array.astype(np.float64)
output_array=data['output'].values.reshape(total_rows,1)
output_array=output_array.astype(np.float64)

weights_in=np.random.uniform(size=(input_neurons,hidden_layer)) 
weights_in=weights_in.astype(np.float64)
bias_in=np.random.uniform(size=(1,hidden_layer))
bias_in=bias_in.astype(np.float64)
weights_out=np.random.uniform(size=(hidden_layer,output_neurons))
weights_out=weights_out.astype(np.float64)
bias_out=np.random.uniform(size=(1,output_neurons))
bias=weights_in.astype(np.float64)

for i in range(epoch):

    #forward propogation
    hidden_layer_output=(np.dot(input_array,weights_in))+bias_in
    activation_1=sigmoid(hidden_layer_output)
    activation_2_input=(np.dot(activation_1,weights_out))+bias_out
    predicted_output=sigmoid(activation_2_input)


    # #backward propogation

    Error=(predicted_output-output_array)

    rate_change_output=derivative_sigmoid(predicted_output)
    rate_change_hidden_output=derivative_sigmoid(activation_1)
    error_on_output=Error*rate_change_output
    error_hidden_layer=error_on_output.dot(weights_out.T)
    delta_hidden_layer=error_hidden_layer*rate_change_hidden_output
    weights_out+=activation_1.T.dot(error_on_output)*learning_rate
    weights_in+=input_array.T.dot(delta_hidden_layer)*learning_rate
    bias_out+=np.sum(error_on_output,axis=0,keepdims=True)*learning_rate
    bias_in+=np.sum(error_hidden_layer,axis=0,keepdims=True)*learning_rate  

print (weights_out)
```

Now when I'm trying to print `weights_out=activation_1.T.dot(error_on_output)*learning_rate` without `for loop` then it gives me correct updated values for `weights_out`. But, as I'm using same piece of code within `for loop` for iteration equals to `epoch` then it returns out as:

```
[[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
```

I have tried each and every line individually and getting correct values and also change dtype as 'float64' but code not seems to work inside `for` loop. Is it something wrong in loop?

Comment: Comment-out `np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore') `. This may give you more information on where the NaNs are coming from.

Comment: @unutbu Checked as you said but still not working. I have checked for epoch value as 5 and getting as `[[30.52973921]
 [31.90311617]
 [31.3969178 ]]
[[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
[[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
[[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
[[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]` loop only worked for one iteration

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think the derivative function should be `1*(1-x)` instead of `1/(1-x)`
This should avoid the zero division and result in correct outputs.

Comment: If you're new to Python, feel free to space out a bit the characters in your code so that the text breathes and is more readable. It's not an .ini file :-) For instance

Comment: `activation_2_input=(np.dot(activation_1,weights_out))+bias_out` can be written `activation_2_input = np.dot(activation_1, weights_out) + bias_out`.

Answer (score 1):

The outputs of `hidden_layer_output` are getting very big (> 20). You are then applying the sigmoid function and the values in `activation_1` are getting close. In fact too close for the computer to differentiate between the value and 1.

When you calculate `rate_change_hidden_output` during backpropagation you are calculating `derivative_sigmoid` of these values. So you are calculating 1/(1-1) whitch results in nan.

These nan-values then propagate through all the values resulting in all values being nan.